# Laravel Elixir / Less include path as folder

Tags: less, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I have been looking but cannot find a way to add a folder to the less include path. or "namespace" it.

Basically rather then "bootstrap" being done like so:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less('app.less', 'public/css/', {
        paths: [
            paths['bootstrap'] + 'less/'
        ]
    });
});
```

It would be like

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less('app.less', 'public/css/', {
        paths: {
            'bootstrap': paths['bootstrap'] + 'less/'
        }
    });
});
```

So if I wanted to call bootstrap in my app.less it would be:

`@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";`

The reason for this is including multiple less resources can sometimes cause multiple files to have the same name.

So is there anyway to do this without moving files around manually?

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to create a directory alias within Less or a derived tool (learn if your OS has such... many do). Besides you can always use [variables in `@import` statements](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-import-statements), e.g.:

```
@bootstrap: "...bla-bla-bla/bootstrap-5.2.8/less"; // can be set via compiler options as well

@import "@{bootstrap}/bootstrap";
```

Comment: I will give this a shot, although I am fairly sure this will work.

Answer (score 0):

My `gulpfile`:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss', 'public/css/', {includePaths: [
        'path/to/bower/components'
    ]});
});
```

Then include vendors like this:

```
@import "bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
@import "fontawesome/scss/font-awesome";
```

Hope I helped you.

Comment: Yes this is one way I have been considering.

Answer (score 0):

I found the magical answer, this although `seven-phases-max` was extremely close, this is just a completed version.

the third variable of `mix.less` is for plugin options, meaning any plugin for less and `modifyVars` is available in the core.

So:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix
        .less('app.less', 'public/css/', {
            modifyVars: {
                'bootstrap': '"' + path.resolve(__dirname) + paths['bootstrap'] + 'less/' + '"'
            }
        })
});
```

Kind of odd having to wrap with `"` but when it adds the variable it adds it raw.

The rest makes use of the other answer, but you can make use of

`@import "@{bootstrap}/bootstrap";`